# PHP AJAX CRUD Issue While Fetching Data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, crud

So I was developing some crud application with CodeIgniter Framework. But I am facing issues while retrieving data from the database. I am getting a `404 Not Found` error for the AJAX function. The function is where it should be but I can't seem to find why it's giving me an error.

Please find the following code for the files and let me know if I am doing anything wrong here.

> package_view.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Package List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <!-- Page Heading -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>Package
                    <small>List</small>
                    <div class="float-right"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal_Add"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Add New</a></div>
                </h1>
            </div>

            <table class="table table-striped" id="mydata">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Package ID</th>
                        <th>Test Quantity</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th style="text-align: right;">Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="show_data">

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

        <!-- MODAL ADD -->
            <form>
            <div class="modal fade" id="Modal_Add" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Add New Package</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Test Quantity</label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                              <input type="text" name="test_quantity" id="test_quantity" class="form-control" placeholder="Test Quantity">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Price</label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                              <input type="text" name="price" id="price" class="form-control" placeholder="Price">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" type="submit" id="btn_save" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        <!--END MODAL ADD-->

        <!-- MODAL EDIT -->
        <form>
            <div class="modal fade" id="Modal_Edit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Package</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Package ID</label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                              <input type="text" name="pkg_id_edit" id="pkg_id_edit" class="form-control" placeholder="Package ID" readonly>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Test Quantity</label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                              <input type="text" name="test_quantity_edit" id="test_quantity_edit" class="form-control" placeholder="Test Quantity">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label class="col-md-2 col-form-label">Price</label>
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                              <input type="text" name="price_edit" id="price_edit" class="form-control" placeholder="Price">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" type="submit" id="btn_update" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        <!--END MODAL EDIT-->

        <!--MODAL DELETE-->
         <form>
            <div class="modal fade" id="Modal_Delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Delete Package</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                       <strong>Are you sure to delete this record?</strong>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <input type="hidden" name="pkg_id_delete" id="pkg_id_delete" class="form-control">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                    <button type="button" type="submit" id="btn_delete" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        <!--END MODAL DELETE-->

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        show_package(); //call function show all package

        $('#mydata').dataTable();

        //function show all package
        function show_package(){
            $.ajax({
                type  : 'ajax',
                url   : '<?php echo site_url('Package/package_data')?>',
                async : true,
                dataType : 'json',
                success : function(data){
                    var html = '';
                    var i;
                    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                        html += '<tr>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].pkg_id+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].test_quantity+'</td>'+
                                '<td>'+data[i].price+'</td>'+
                                '<td style="text-align:right;">'+
                                    '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-info btn-sm item_edit" data-pkg_id="'+data[i].pkg_id+'" data-test_quantity="'+data[i].test_quantity+'" data-price="'+data[i].price+'">Edit</a>'+' '+
                                    '<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm item_delete" data-pkg_id="'+data[i].pkg_id+'">Delete</a>'+
                                '</td>'+
                                '</tr>';
                    }
                    $('#show_data').html(html);
                }

            });
        }

        //Save package
        $('#btn_save').on('click',function(){
            var pkg_id = $('#pkg_id').val();
            var test_quantity = $('#test_quantity').val();
            var price = $('#price').val();
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url  : "<?php echo site_url('Package/save')?>",
                dataType : "JSON",
                data : {pkg_id:pkg_id , test_quantity:test_quantity, price:price},
                success: function(data){
                    $('[name="pkg_id"]').val("");
                    $('[name="test_quantity"]').val("");
                    $('[name="price"]').val("");
                    $('#Modal_Add').modal('hide');
                    show_package();
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

        //get data for update record
        $('#show_data').on('click','.item_edit',function(){
            var pkg_id = $(this).data('pkg_id');
            var test_quantity = $(this).data('test_quantity');
            var price = $(this).data('price');

            $('#Modal_Edit').modal('show');
            $('[name="pkg_id_edit"]').val(pkg_id);
            $('[name="test_quantity_edit"]').val(test_quantity);
            $('[name="price_edit"]').val(price);
        });

        //update record to database
         $('#btn_update').on('click',function(){
            var pkg_id = $('#pkg_id_edit').val();
            var test_quantity = $('#test_quantity_edit').val();
            var price        = $('#price_edit').val();
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url  : "<?php echo site_url('Package/update')?>",
                dataType : "JSON",
                data : {pkg_id:pkg_id , test_quantity:test_quantity, price:price},
                success: function(data){
                    $('[name="pkg_id_edit"]').val("");
                    $('[name="test_quantity_edit"]').val("");
                    $('[name="price_edit"]').val("");
                    $('#Modal_Edit').modal('hide');
                    show_package();
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

        //get data for delete record
        $('#show_data').on('click','.item_delete',function(){
            var pkg_id = $(this).data('pkg_id');

            $('#Modal_Delete').modal('show');
            $('[name="pkg_id_delete"]').val(pkg_id);
        });

        //delete record to database
         $('#btn_delete').on('click',function(){
            var pkg_id = $('#pkg_id_delete').val();
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url  : "<?php echo site_url('Package/delete')?>",
                dataType : "JSON",
                data : {pkg_id:pkg_id},
                success: function(data){
                    $('[name="pkg_id_delete"]').val("");
                    $('#Modal_Delete').modal('hide');
                    show_package();
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

    });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Packages.php

```
<?php
class Packages extends CI_Controller{
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('package_model');
}
function index(){
    $this->load->view('package_view');
}

function package_data(){
    $data=$this->package_model->package_list();
    echo json_encode($data);
}

function save(){
    $data=$this->package_model->save_package();
    echo json_encode($data);
}

function update(){
    $data=$this->package_model->update_package();
    echo json_encode($data);
}

function delete(){
    $data=$this->package_model->delete_package();
    echo json_encode($data);
}
}
```

and

> package_model.php

```
<?php
class package_model extends CI_Model{

function package_list(){
    $hasil=$this->db->get('tblexampackages');
    return $hasil->result();
}

function save_package(){
    $data = array(
            'pkg_id'  => $this->input->post('pkg_id'), 
            'test_quantity'  => $this->input->post('test_quantity'), 
            'price' => $this->input->post('price'), 
        );
    $result=$this->db->insert('tblexampackages',$data);
    return $result;
}

function update_package(){
    $pkg_id=$this->input->post('pkg_id');
    $test_quantity=$this->input->post('test_quantity');
    $price=$this->input->post('price');

    $this->db->set('price', $price);
    $this->db->set('test_quantity', $test_quantity);
    $this->db->where('pkg_id', $pkg_id);
    $result=$this->db->update('tblexampackages');
    return $result;
}

function delete_package(){
    $pkg_id=$this->input->post('pkg_id');
    $this->db->where('pkg_id', $pkg_id);
    $result=$this->db->delete('tblexampackages');
    return $result;
}

}
```

Other files are `autoload.php`, `config.php` and `database.php` which are configured properly. Please tell me where I am going wrong here.

As for database, MySQL connectivity is good and the table named `tblexampackages` only has 3 Columns named `pkg_id`, `test_quantity` and `price`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller is Packages, you're trying to access Package... Edit this line from

```
url   : '<?php echo site_url('Package/package_data')?>', //old

url   : "<?php echo site_url('Packages/package_data')?>" //new
```

After which, edit your package_list to something like this

```
$query = $this->db->get('tbl_name');
return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: That's a very very very dumb mistake. And thanks for notifying. It solved the problem however search Isn't working. Did you find any other mistake?

Comment: And pagination not working properly too. I know you solved the question you asked and I am grateful for that but can you please help me a bit more

Comment: I don't understand what u mean y search isn't working. In your ajax requests, always add a code to e executed if the call fails. after success, always add error(response){ console.log(response)} That is going to help us see the exact error

Comment: Thanks. I'll see what I can do. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in your Ajax function show_package() you have:

```
url   : '<?php echo site_url('Package/package_data')?>',
```

it should be

```
url   : '<?php echo site_url('Packages/package_data')?>',
```